# No such built-in module "readline/promises"

Tags: node.js

I'm having problems using readline, every time I get the error No such built-in module: node:readline/promises. However according to Readline's own doc I would only need this part https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline/promises';
import { stdin as input, stdout as output } from 'node:process';

const rl = readline.createInterface({ input, output });
```

[Image of the package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzNCe.png)

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvZKo.png)

I'm sorry if this is a question that has already been answered before, but I couldn't find anything that would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be dependent on which version of node you're running. Different versions have different ways of importing built in modules. If you don't know which version you're on, run `node -v` on the console, the go to the node readline documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline), go to Other Versions at the top and select your node version.

Comment: yeap, i was trying to with the latest version and i was using the LTS v16.17.0 haha, thanks a lot!!